# Alternative tools for Amazon EC2?

Tags: unix, command-line, amazon-ec2

Amazon's official tools for interacting with EC2 are kind of clunky and a pain to deal with. I have to set up a bunch of environment variables, store separate private keys just for EC2, add extra items to my PATH, and so on. They all output tab delimited lines that are hundreds of characters long with no headings, so it's a bit of a pain to interpret them. Their instructions for setting up an SSH keypair give you one that isn't protected by a passphrase, rather than letting you use an existing keypair that you already have. The programs are all just a bit clunky and aren't very good Unix programs.

So, are there any easier to use command line tools for accessing EC2? I know there is ElasticFox, and there is their web based console, which do make the process easier, but I'm wondering if anyone else has written better command line tools for interacting with EC2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm a bit late but I have a solution!

I found the same problems with the Amazon AMI tools. They're a decent reference implementation but very difficult to use particularly when you have more than a couple instances. I wrote a replacement command-line tool as part of another project, called Rudy that answers most of your concerns

The commands are more intuitive than Amazon's AMI tools:

- `rudy-ec2 instances -C`
- `rudy-ec2 groups -A -p 8080 -a 11.22.33.44 group-name`
- `rudy-ec2 volumes -C -s 100`
- `rudy-ec2 images`
- ...

All configuration is in a single file (`~/.rudy/config`).

It can output in several formats (yaml, json, csv, tsv, and of course regular text):

```
rudy-ec2 -f yaml snapshots
--- 
:awsid: snap-2457b24d
:progress: 100%
:created: "2009-05-08T15:24:17.000Z"
:volid: vol-4ee10427
:status: completed
```

Regarding the private keys, There are no EC2 tools that allow to create private keys for with a password *for booting a public instance* because the API doesn't support it. However, if you create your own image, you can use your private keys.

Here's more info:

- [GitHub Project](http://github.com/solutious/rudy/tree/master)
- [An introduction to rudy-ec2](http://solutious.com/blog/2009/04/22/rudy-ec2-api-tools-replacement/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and for writing Rudy! The next time I need to boot up an instance, I will try out Rudy and Tim Kay's perl based command line tools from the earlier answer (I don't use EC2 that often, I just occasionally boot an OpenSolaris instance or Fedora instance for testing something out that I can't test under Mac OS X and Ubuntu). Thanks also for the answer about creating private keys with a password, though it's rather frustrating, as I can't see any reason why they wouldn't just let you upload your own public key.

Answer (score 4):

ElasticFox is handy for most tasks. They are occasions though that a command line tool will be better suited. I personally use [boto](http://code.google.com/p/boto/) library for python. It is very easy to script all the required operations. You can also use it to upload/download files from S3. In general, I would say that a scripting language like Python or RUby, together with a AWS library, is the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

I personally use Tim Kay's Perl [command line tools](http://timkay.com/aws/) and haven't used original Java based API for quite some time. Excellent for UNIX environment.

Comment: This tool also work well under Windows, and it also supports S3 and SQS.

Comment: It now supports s3, ec2, sdb, elb, sqs, and (soon) iam.

Answer (score 3):

Not command line, but take a look at what a free [RightScale](http://www.rightscale.com) account will give you -  much, much easier than command line or ElasticFox IMO.

Comment: RightScale is expensive.  Their fees will add 50% on top of your EC2 bill.

Answer (score 1):

About ec2-api-tools:

I agree that they are a bit too clunky, I particular dislike the output of ec2-describe-instances.
I recently switched to python-boto which offers a very clean and easy to use interface to ec2.

About not being able to specify a passphrase for the ssh key generated by EC2:

That's not the case. You can change the passphrase of any ssh private key anytime, using:

```
ssh-keygen -p -f /path/to/keyfile
```

E.g.

```
ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

About uploading your own ssh key pair:

You can use ec2-import-keypair, like this:

```
for i in $(ec2-describe-regions|cut -f 2);do
  ec2-import-keypair --region $i mykey --public-key-file ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
done
```

The example above will upload the public key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to every region under the name "mykey". Remember that each region has it's own keypair.

In order to have the key installed in your ec2 instances, you'll have to pass the "-k mykey" option to ec2-run-instances.

Incidentally, uploading your own keypair is the only way to login with the same key to all the instances in all regions. If you create the keypair from the web interface, you'll have a different key in every region.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I asked this question in 2009, and `ec2-import-keypair` wasn't implemented until [2010](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/4174?_encoding=UTF8&fromSearch=1&queryArg=searchQuery&searchPath=releasenotes&searchQuery=ec2-import-keypair&x=0&y=0); at the time I asked the question, this wasn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have an open source graphical system admin tool called EC2Dream that replaces the command line tool. It installs on windows, linux and Mac OS clients and is written in Ruby and FXRuby. See www.ec2dream.com.

Neill Turner

[www.ec2dream.com](http://www.ec2dream.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows, try the tool linked below (part of the [O2 Platform](http://o2platform.com)) which gives you an easy way to start and stop Amazon EC2 images (and if you need to extend the tool it you can easily add new features (since it just an C# script that is dynamically compiled and executed)

- [O2 Tool – Amazon EC2 Browser](http://o2platform.wordpress.com/2011/04/08/o2-tool-amazon-ec2-browser/)
- [Amazon EC2 Browser – Timer to Stop Instances](http://o2platform.wordpress.com/2011/04/10/amazon-ec2-browser-timer-to-stop-instances/)

Answer (score 0):

the problem with alternative libraries is that they are not always kept up to date, so if new features for AWS are released, then you need to wait. You posted that your main problems are the bunch of environment variables, add extra items to your PATH, etc. We had this
issue at [BitNami](http://bitnami.org/), and is the main reason we created [BitNami Cloud Tools](http://bitnami.org/tools/cloud) that ships all of the AWS command line tools together with preconfigured Java and Ruby language runtimes. You only have to download it and everything that you need will be installed in a folder without modify your system configuration. We keep it regularly up to date.

Answer (score 0):

There is an entire industry called **Cloud Management** which try to solve this type of problems. **Scalr** and **RightScale** and the leaders in this sector (disclaimer: I work at Scalr).

Cloud management softwares are built on top of Amazon EC2 API (and usually on other public IaaS like Rackspace) and provide an improved user interface along with automation tools like backups or SSH management as you mentioned it. They don't provide easier command lines tools stricto sensu. Their goal is to make interaction with Amazon EC2 easier.

Different options are available in the market:

- **Scalr**: [Scalr](http://scalr.net) is available as a hosted service with a trial version.
  Otherwise you can [download](http://scalr.net/pricing/open-source/) and install the source code yourself, as it is released under the Apache 2 license.
- **RightScale**: while they are usually considered as expensive for small businesses, they do offer a free account.
- **enStratus**: they offer a freemium model like RightScale.